# How can I map a list of IDs to a list of Entities using AutoMapper.Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper

I'm using Entity Framework Core in a C# WebAPI project. I have the following entities (simplified for the purposes of this example):

```csharp
public class Division
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int DivisionID { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<CompetitorLevel> CompetitorLevels { get; set; }
}
```

```csharp
public class CompetitorLevel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int CompetitorLevelID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
}
```

```csharp
public class DivisionDTO
{
    public int? id { get; set; }

    public List<string> competitorLevels { get; set; }
}
```

The DTO is used to send and receive data to/from my frontend app.

I'm successfully using AutoMapper to map the straightforward properties, and to map from a `Division` to a `DivisionDTO`, no problem there. **My problem is that I can't get conversion from the list of IDs on the DTO to a list of entities working.**

I tried AutoMapper.Collection using every permutation of `.EqualityComparison(...)` or `.MapFrom(...)` that I could think of; using lists, selecting IDs, etc.. but I can't get it to work.

My solution right now is to build and map the entities manually in my service class, which is probably fine, but I feel like there may be a more elegant way of doing this in AutoMapper. Here is the solution in my service:

```csharp
public void Update(DivisionDTO request)
{
    if (request.id == null)
        throw new ValidationException("The ID attribute is required.");

    Division division = _db.Divisions
        .Include(d => d.CompetitorLevels)
        .FirstOrDefault(d => d.DivisionID == request.id.Value);

    if (division == null)
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("A division with that ID was not found.");

    _mapper.Map(request, division);
    UpdateCompetitorLevels(request, division);

    _db.SaveChanges();
}

public void UpdateCompetitorLevels(DivisionDTO request, Division division)
{
    // Remove competitor levels from division if not present in DTO
    foreach (CompetitorLevel competitorLevel in division.CompetitorLevels.ToList())
    {
        if (!request.competitorLevels.Select(cl => int.Parse(cl)).Contains(competitorLevel.CompetitorLevelID))
        {
            (division.CompetitorLevels as List<CompetitorLevel>).Remove(competitorLevel);
        }
    }

    // Add competitor level to division if present in DTO
    foreach (int competitorLevelID in request.competitorLevels.Select(cl => int.Parse(cl)))
    {
        if (!division.CompetitorLevels.Any(cl => cl.CompetitorLevelID == competitorLevelID))
        {
            (division.CompetitorLevels as List<CompetitorLevel>).Add(_db.CompetitorLevels.Find(competitorLevelID));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the Map bewteen string and CompetitorLevel as below:

```
public class DivisionProfile:Profile
    {
        public DivisionProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<DivisionDTO, Division>().ForMember(x=>x.CompetitorLevels,y=>y.MapFrom(x=>x.competitorLevels)).ForMember(x=>x.DivisionID,y=>y.MapFrom(x=>x.id));
            CreateMap<string, CompetitorLevel>().ForMember(x => x.CompetitorLevelID, y => y.MapFrom(x => int.Parse(x)));
   
        }
    }
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I see, so you map the CompetitorLevels to a string in the root mapping, and then specify how to convert from a string to a CompetitorLevel object. I will try that tonight, thank you for your answer.